# How Do I Stop the User from Scrolling at a Certain Point?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I have been looking for a solution that would work for a good while now but honestly everything I try falls short. I have built a website and would like to prevent the user from scrolling past 6200px from the top (the page is around 8240px long). It'll be long to explain why I need help with this but basically, it's some patchwork that's needed to be done. I understand CSS and JS but my JS isn't amazing...A lot of the answers I have seen before are in jQuery, which is fine but I would appreciate some explanation on how to implement it into my HTML as I'm kind of new to the coding game.

Any help would be amazing!
Thanks!

Comment: What should happen when they reach the end? Prevent them from scrolling?

Comment: Are you able to add something to the HTML?

Comment: Sorry just seen your replies @AHaworth and @MaartenDev! Yes, I can add something to my HTML and yeah so the problem is I have a tone of <div>s pushed upwards so they all overlap one another creating a cool layering effect. the problem is there is a ton of empty space at the bottom of the page now which I can't fill with anything... hence why I want to stop users from scrolling past a point. I can see how I messed up and could have done it better to create the same effect but honestly, I just want to finish this project up and move on the my next project (to further my understanding of coding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with sensing the scroll event and acting on just that is that the user may have shot past the 6200px point as you don't get told about the event until the scrolling has happened. So for example think of a very fast intertial scroll on a tablet - finger flicking wildly to go down.

So we need to make sure that if they do shoot past they don't see anything.

We can do these things:

- Hide everything below 6200px with a pseudo div - can't stop a nosey user looking at what's underneath using browser dev tools, but can stop people accidentally seeing the stuff that's there
- Plant a 1pixel div at 6199px and set up an intersectionObserver on it so we know when the user is entering the danger zone and force scrollTo just to show the final viewport's worth of 'allowed' content.

```js
function callback(entries) {
  if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
    window.scrollTo({top: Number(6200 - window.innerHeight), left: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
  }
}
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback);
  observer.observe(document.querySelector('#sensor'));
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
.talldiv::after {
  height: calc(100% - 6200px);
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6200px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 99999;
}
#sensor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 6199px;
}
.talldiv {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 8000px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, purple, orange, yellow, green, blue, cyan, magenta, gray);
}
```

```html
<div id="sensor"></div>
<div class="talldiv">SCOLL DOWN</div>
```

I had thought that we shouldn't have to do any more but on a laptop it has been possible to 'break through' and scroll past 6200px if scrolling fast in large chunks. I need to add a bit to sense when the sensor has gone off the top of the viewport rather than just when it comes into the viewport.

Comment: Actually worked! Thank you so much! plus your solution is so simple and makes so much sense.

Comment: Actually so happy with the results! Thanks again @AHaworth

Answer (score 0):

here is a small approch to that. According to Dharman you've to scroll a little bit to the top again, that everything below 6200px is not "visible".

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).scroll(function() {
    var top_of_element = $("#dont-show").offset().top;
    var bottom_of_element = $("#dont-show").offset().top + $("#dont-show").outerHeight();
    var bottom_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight();
    var top_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop();

    if ((bottom_of_screen > top_of_element) && (top_of_screen < bottom_of_element)){
        // the element is visible, do something
        console.log("visible");
        $(window).scrollTop(bottom_of_screen - bottom_of_element);
    } else {
        // the element is not visible, do something else
        console.log("not visible");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Dont scroll below 6200p</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <div style="width:100%;height:100vh;background-color: blue;"></div>
  <div id="dont-show" style="width:100%;height:10vh;background-color: red;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You could now modify this source code so that the offset of the window is queried upwards and scrolled over accordingly if the user has scrolled below 6200px.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! but I've been trying to get it to work for a good hour and honestly can't get it to work... any advice on getting it to work... feels like I'm missing something super simple but it's not working?

Answer (score -1):

Hello and welcome to the Stackoverflow community!

To prevent the user from scrolling you would either have to create a loop which redirects user if they go to that certain point to upper area or you can make the page small or cut short.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast reply and a helpful message!